# tkinter and thread arguments

Tags: python, tkinter, parameter-passing

I have a simple ui written by python tkinter, it only contains one button.

I found a problem here, if the button command is directed to a function, which includes creating an instance to perform its method. However, when i run this program, my pycharm told me I am passing one positional argument to the method, which i never did:

TypeError: tell_time() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

For some reasons, I have to keep the method stay within the class. Could anyone tell me how to let the method run? Thanks a million!

```
def build_ui():

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Auto Hedger")
    root.geometry("640x480")

    btn1 = Button(root, text="get data", command=testing1)
    btn1.pack()


    root.mainloop()

class test_object():
    def tell_time():
        print(datetime.datetime.now())

def testing1():
    aaa = test_object()
    t1000 = Thread(target=aaa.tell_time, args=[])
    t1000.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    t_root = Thread(target=build_ui)
    t_root.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `tell_time` method needs `self` as a parameter, since it is a class method and not a function. Adding that should make it work fine.
Try this:

```
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import *
import datetime

def build_ui():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Auto Hedger")
    root.geometry("640x480")

    btn1 = Button(root, text="get data", command=testing1)
    btn1.pack()

    root.mainloop()

class test_object():
    def tell_time(self):
        print(datetime.datetime.now())

def testing1():
    aaa = test_object()
    t1000 = Thread(target=aaa.tell_time, args=[])
    t1000.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t_root = Thread(target=build_ui)
    t_root.start()
```

Comment: Or just put `@staticmethod` before your `def tell_time()`.